# How to configure Maven to ignore for local install and force JDK version

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have a Maven project whose repository has a restriction, one of this is a JDK restriction and want only 1.5.0-4, 1.6.0-45, 1.7.0-80, 1.8.0-71. I have JDK 1.8.0-65 and when I make an MVN install shows me the error below:

```
Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.8.0-65 is not in the allowed range [1.5.0-4,1.5.0-4],[1.6.0-45,1.6.0-45],[1.7.0-80,1.7.0-80],[1.8.0-71,).
```

Does any way exist to configure Maven to ignore that restriction in local install? Without installing another version of JDK. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maven enforcer plugin is apparently used in this project. You can skip this plugin with the skip flag. E.g.

```
mvn clean install -Denforcer.skip=true
```

You may find out that the author had good reason to require java later than *1.8.0-71* mind you.

[maven enforcer plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: I think that is a shame for the author of that repository to force only one version of jdk.. I don't know why for the moment

Comment: the allowed range is reported as `[1.8.0-71,)`. That means "1.8.0-71 or later"

Comment: For only java 8, but the company have some project that use java 7 or 6.

Answer (score 2):

I find another way. Putting inside a settings.xml under .m2 this code:

```
            <properties>
                <revision>LOCAL</revision>
                <enforcer.fail>false</enforcer.fail>
            </properties>
```

This properties shuold be inside `profile` tag

Comment: In this way you can make just a mvn install